# Null pointer exception while passing object from LWC to Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to get user input from a lightning web component and pass it to apex class. But getting the status 500, system.nullpointer exception. It seems that the object I am passing is null. When I print the object it is showing as null. How can I overcome this issue?

HTML :

```
<template>
    <lightning-card  title="Add Profile and Permission Sets">

        <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter the profile" name = "profile" value = {profile} placeholder="type here..." maxlength="25"></lightning-input>

        <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter the permissionsets semicolon seperated"  name = "permissions" value = {permissions} placeholder="type here..." maxlength="25"></lightning-input>

        <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={handleReset}>Reset</button>  

    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

LWC :

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import handleInsertAndUpdate from '@salesforce/apex/metadataInsertUpdate.handleInsertAndUpdate';
import SystemModstamp from '@salesforce/schema/Account.SystemModstamp';

export default class PermissionSetAssign extends LightningElement {

    handleSubmit(event) {

        //handle onclick event
        let profile = this.template.querySelector(`[name="profile"]`);
        let permissions = this.template.querySelector(`[name="permissions"]`);
        // Map<String, Object> or a single mapping
        var object = {'Profile__c': profile, 'Permissions__c': permissions};
        console.log(object);
        //The developerName is Profile_Permission.ProfileName and label is ProfileName
        //handleInsertAndUpdate('Profile_Permission.'+profile , profile , JSON.stringify(object));

        handleInsertAndUpdate({fullName:'Profile_Permission.'+profile},{label: profile}, {fieldWithValuesMap: object}).then(result=>{
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log(error);
        })
    
        //Show toast message
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Toast Success',
            message: 'Opearion sucessful',
            variant: 'success',
            mode: 'dismissable'
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);

        console.log("Error " + this.errorCallback.message);

    }

    handleReset(){
        this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(element => {
            element.value = null;      
          });
    }

}
```

Apex Class :

```
public class metadataInsertUpdate implements Metadata.DeployCallback {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void handleResult(Metadata.DeployResult result, Metadata.DeployCallbackContext context) {
        if (result.status == Metadata.DeployStatus.Succeeded) {

            System.debug('success: '+ result);
            } else {      
            System.debug(' fail: '+ result);
            }
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void handleInsertAndUpdate (String fullName, String label, Map<String, String> fieldWithValuesMap){

        Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadata = new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
        customMetadata.fullName = fullName;
        customMetadata.label = label;
        
        for (String key: fieldWithValuesMap.keySet()) {
        
           Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
           customField.field = key;
           customField.value = fieldWithValuesMap.get(key);
           customMetadata.values.add(customField);
        }
        
        Metadata.DeployContainer mdContainer = new Metadata.DeployContainer(); 
        mdContainer.addMetadata(customMetadata);
        metadataInsertUpdate callback = new metadataInsertUpdate();       
        Id jobId = Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(mdContainer, callback);
        
        }
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass in entire `lightning-input` elements instead of their values. Instead, you need to get the value:

```
let profile = this.template.querySelector('[name="profile"]').value;
let permissions = this.template.querySelector('[name="permissions"]').value;
var object = { Profile__c: profile, Permissions__c: permissions };
```

Comment: Hi, still I am getting the same error.